# CloudFront could not contact origin lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I've create a cloudfront distribution that points to my lambda function arn.

[image]

I also have tested the lambda function which returns the correct response...

[image]

Lastly I have my origin setup

[image]

[image]

When I click on the direct link http://d298egxp5ql8u2.cloudfront.net/ I get a could not contact origin error. What is causing this?

Also, I've migrated my domain registrar to aws but my custom domain doesn't work at all devrx01.centari.io. I don't even get that error. The documentation on AWS isn't helping at this point and I have no clue. Why isn't cloudfront talking to my lambda service?

Comment: It's really not clear why you have http://devrx01.centari.io (a non-working hostname) as your origin domain name or why you configured the Lambda function ARN as your Origin ID.  Origin ID is just a label.  To generate content from a Lambda@Edge function, you need a viewer request or origin request trigger for the function, in the cache behavior settings.  Do you have that?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an s3 origin and I saw some blog post use the arn of the lambda as the origin. I was hoping my node application could just dynamically create content rather than point it to an s3. So an s3 origin is not necessary because I'd intercept every request anyway... unless cloudfront lambda@edge was not built for my use case.

Comment: Your use case is fine -- slightly outside the box, but quite legitimate -- you'll just need some kind of valid origin server because CloudFront expects one.  An empty bucket would suffice, or, I have found that you can use "invalid.invalid" as the origin domain name for applications where all requests are intercepted by Lambda (so there is no real origin.)  You wouldn't want to use the domain name that you're planning to point to CloudFront, since that would create a loop if your trigger config was missing or a bug allowed it to pass requests through.  Share a link to the blog post?